# Loading a specific function instead of a complete package in R

Tags: r

Is it possible to load only a specific function from a R package without downloading the complete package. We have a similar functionality in Python. Sometimes, R packages are pretty big and take time to get downloaded and installed.

Comment: In your last point are you talking about installing the package or loading it?  There is no way to get around installing the package unless you count taking the code for the specific function you're interested in and just taking that and putting it into it's own script (although this can be more work than you might think due to dependencies on other functions in the package)

Comment: Hi,I meant downloading only a specific function I require instead of the whole package..

Comment: Can't do it. You have to install the entire package.  It's possible to just load a single function (kind of) once it's installed but you can't get around installing the entire package.

Comment: See Dason's first comment. It is possible, but you have to find the source and 'do something' with it (run it in your current R session or incorporate it into another, faster, loading package. Good luck with satisfying all the dependencies, as Dason already pointed out.